# Recurrence Analysis (Time complexity)

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

im writing a boolean function that calculate if two binary trees are identical.
Lets see the program:

```
boolean func(Node head1 , Node head2){
if(head1 == null || head2 == null) return head1 == null && head2 == null;
return func(head1.left , head2.left) && (head1.right,head2.right);
}
```

i know that in the worst case the program check n element so its O(n).
and i want to describe this recurrence function in T(n).
i dont know were to start becuse i dont know what is the value of the stopping point ,
i think that the function is T(n,m) = 2*t(n-1,m-1) + n + m.

Answer (score 0):

Let `n` be the number of nodes in the binary trees. If the binary trees have different number of nodes, then `n` is smaller of the two sizes (since you'll stop comparing once you reach the end of one tree).

On each call you are doing some comparisons between the nodes of the tree. This will be in constant time, so you can call this time spent `d` which represents some arbitrary constant.

Lastly, you're making 2 recursive calls for the current node's 2 children. Note that in the worst case, each of the children are the root of a subtree that holds half the total number of nodes in the tree. In other words if you have a tree with `n` nodes, and you are looking at the root node, then each child of the root has about n/2 nodes below it (and including it).

So your recurrence is as follows:

`T(n) = 2*T((n-1)/2) + d`

You can simplify this to:

`T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + d`